# How Can I Turn Off RISC-V Compressed Instructions?

Tags: cross-compiling, riscv

When I use the riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc, there is few differences between option `-march=rv64g` and `-march=rv64gc`.

`-march=64g` will use RVC codes in standard library functions, for example, the prinft,  as much as possible but not in my own functions. While the `-march=64gc`, use the RVC codes in both types of functions.

I don't know whether this is default. But if I want to forbid the RVC codes so that even in the standard library functions without the RVC codes, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Recompile the riscv-gnu-tool with option `--with-arch=rv64g --disable-multilib`

Comment: Instead of riscv-gnu-tool did you mean https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following with `gcc` (11.3.0) and `clang` (17.0.0) on RISC-V hardware (underlying `uarch` of `sifive,u74-mc` with `isa` of `rv64imafdc`) to use uncompressed RISC-V instructions.

`hello.S`:

```
.global main

.data
hello:  .asciz "Hello, world!\n"

.text
main:
  addi sp,sp,-8
  sd   ra,0(sp)

  la   a0,hello
  call printf

  li   a0,0
  ld   ra,0(sp)
  addi sp,sp,8
  ret
```

`gcc -march=rv64g -o hello hello.S` or `clang -march=rv64g -o hello hello.S`.  Verify that your code has uncompressed instructions:

```
objdump -d -M no-aliases hello

...
0000000000000668 <main>:
 668:   ff810113            addi    sp,sp,-8
 66c:   00113023            sd  ra,0(sp)
 670:   00002517            auipc   a0,0x2
 674:   9d053503            ld  a0,-1584(a0) # 2040 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 678:   f29ff0ef            jal ra,5a0 <printf@plt>
 67c:   00000513            addi    a0,zero,0
 680:   00013083            ld  ra,0(sp)
 684:   00810113            addi    sp,sp,8
 688:   00008067            jalr    zero,0(ra)
```

Two things to note:  the instructions are 32-bits wide, and they do not have `c.` in front of them.

Finally note that the executable is linked with standard libraries, and those libraries may have been compiled with support of the `c` extension.  You can confirm this with `-M no-aliases` to `objdump -D` and instructions that look like `c.beqz`, `c.addi`, etc.