# How to turn off the use of compression instructions (RVC) when compiling code with gcc of RISC-V64?

Tags: gcc, riscv

I use the 11.1.0 version of the riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc tool to compile the c code, and now there is a need to turn off RVC, how do I do this?

`gccrv64e -march=rv64imafd  arch-fib.c -o arch-fib`

I tried to block RVC using the following command, but failed. The disassembly result still has RVC instructions.

Is there any way I can remove RVC during the compilation process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forbid the riscv compressed codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704690/how-to-forbid-the-riscv-compressed-codes)

Answer (score 1):

There is two reasons of that:

1. You compiled toolchain with compressed enabled, and when you look in dissassembly, you see compressed instructions of `crt0` file, and you think that `C` extension won't disable. Look int `main` function and you will see it have no `Compressed` instructions.
2. You incorrectly compiled toolchain (idk how, but this possible, i ran into this once), and toolchain still add `RVC` even if you use flag `rv64g` or any other without `RVC`. Try to type `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -v` and watch your configured build.